# ManyRelatedManager call returns empty list when it should return at least one result

Tags: django, django-models

I have two models designated for tracking what users have upvoted an Article instance (in another app, in this case `articlescraper`).

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

class UserProfile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User)

    articles_upvoted = models.ManyToManyField('useraccounts.UpvotedArticle',
                                              null=True,
                                              blank=True)

class UpvotedArticle(models.Model):
    article = models.ForeignKey('articlescraper.Article')
    user = models.ForeignKey(User)
```

In a Django shell, I've tried to get a list of articles by interacting with `UserProfile`:

```
a = UserProfile.objects.get(pk=1)
a.articles_upvoted.all()
```

Which returns:

```
[]
```

However, then I went a little further:

```
b = UpvotedArticle.objects.filter(user=User.objects.get(pk=1))
b
```

Which returns:

```
[<UpvotedArticle: Arch Linux Lexmark S305 Drivers>, <UpvotedArticle: Structure of a Haystack project>]
```

Which is the expected behavior, and is mirrored in the Django admin in both `UserProfile` and `UpvotedArticle` categories.

I don't understand, however, why attempting to get a list of articles can't be done the way I initially tried to using `a.articles_upvoted.all()` if the two models are linked.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because these aren't the same relationship. By defining a ForeignKey on one side, and a ManyToMany on the other, you've given the database two separate places to store information about article upvoting.

You should remove the `ManyToManyField` on `UserProfile`, and just use the automatic reverse relationship:

```
a = UserProfile.objects.get(pk=1)
a.upvotedarticle_set.all()
```

Alternatively, you could recognize `UpvotedArticle` as the "through" table of the ManyToMany relationship, and mark it as such explicitly in the definition of `articles_upvoted` - note though that the relationship should be with `articlescraper.Article`, not `UpvotedArticle`:

```
article_upvoted = models.ManyToManyField(articlescraper.Article, null=True,
                                         blank=True, through=UpvotedArticle)
```

Although since you're not adding any extra data on that relationship, which is the usual reason for defining an explicit through table, you may want to drop it completely and just rely on the automatic one that Django will create.